# Eclipse doesnt 'release' .exe after Run

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse-cdt

I am using following Software: Eclipse 20190917-1200, minGW GCG, Windows 10.

I use the "C++ Managed Build" Wizard and select "Hello World C++ Project". Then I build the program pressing CTRL+B and get the following output.

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\HelloWorld.o" "..\\src\\HelloWorld.cpp" 
g++ -o HelloWorld.exe "src\\HelloWorld.o" 

15:22:23 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.262ms)
```

I am also able to run the HelloWorld.exe in eclipse and see "Hello World" in the console. Everything fine so far.

Then I make a little change in line 14 and replace
`cout << "Hello World" << endl; // prints Hello World`
with
`cout << "Hello World again" << endl; // prints Hello World`

and try to build again. This will fail with the following error:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\HelloWorld.o" "..\\src\\HelloWorld.cpp" 
g++ -o HelloWorld.exe "src\\HelloWorld.o" 
C:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file HelloWorld.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

15:26:16 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.111ms)
```

So it seems like HelloWorld.exe is still running. However, eclipse says it was terminated. And there is also no process of HelloWorld.exe showing up in the Task Manager.

At first I am unable to delete the  "HelloWorld.exe" file in Eclipse or Windows (Permission denied). When I close eclipse the .exe can be deleted and I am able to build again.

So it seems some part of eclipse reads the .exe and prevents me from deleting it but I really have no idea what this could be.

Comment: Maybe your antivirus is the problem. I would doubt that the IDE is the problem. Are you using defender or some other AV like aVast?

Comment: I tried to follow this idea and disabled antivirus (avira), but no success. Also I am able to delete the .exe after quitting eclipse, so I think eclipse has something to do with this.

Comment: @bb8-droid Not your question and you may have your reasons but Eclipse is the last thing I would recommend for C++ development on Windows,